# Ubuntu 13.10 rdesktop issuse with local printer

Tags: 13.10, usb, windows-7, printing, remote-desktop

I have a Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit installed on my machine. I am using `rdesktop` to remote into a Windows 7 Pro 32-bit machine. I have a local printer that is connected via `USB` to my Ubuntu machine. The local printer is a Brother MFC-J430W. I want to share the printer to the Windows 7 machine. Here is the syntax that I have tried to use:

```
rdesktop -r printer:MFCJ430W="MFCJ430W" -f -x l -u mikej -d  Test win-7-32
```

After I enter the command, the remote desktop comes up fine, but I don't have local printer in Windows 7. Can some please tell me what I am doing wrong?